# Inspecting NullPointer setVisibility case

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

In my crash log I see occasionally this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
   at AbstractFragment.init(Unknown Source)
   at ExtendingFragment.onEnabled(Unknown Source)
   at ExtendingFragment.enableScrolling(Unknown Source)
   at ExtendingFragment$7.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
```

...

that easy, right? problem is surely in `AbstractFragment.init`, but:

```
void init(MyPOJO myPOJO, View.OnClickListener aListener, View.OnClickListener bListener,
                    boolean stored) {
    this.myPOJO= myPOJO;
    this.aListener = aListener;
    this.bListener = bListener;
    this.stored = stored;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

    used = new SparseBooleanArray();
    verticalMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.article_spacing_vertical);
    horizontalMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.article_spacing_horizontal);
    if (samsung_4_4_have_bug == null) //static
        samsung_4_4_have_bug = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19 &&
                Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("samsung");
}
```

any `setVisibility` call in here, in fact it's just a "setter". So maybe in `ExtendingFragment.onEnabled`? Lets see:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(int pendingId) {
    if (pendingId == localId && someView != null)
        someView.post(() -> someView.callOnClick());
}
```

no `setVisibility` also... inside attached `OnClickListener` there is no `setVisibility` and also no `AbstractFragment.init` calls...

inside `ExtendingFragment.enableScrolling` I'm preparing few listeners, but no `setVisibility` call in any

`ExtendingFragment$7.onClick` suggest that this `NullPointer` occurs after some `OnClick`, but I've checked ALL `OnClickListeners` in both fragment layers and you will never guess... There is no `setVisibility` call in any of these...

so how to resolve this? I'm using some `visibility` switching, but not in any of listed in stack methods. how to inspect that?

Comment: Looks like the stacktrace is from a proguard-optimized build. The optimization can inline methods etc. so the stacktraces are not always accurate. Look for code nearby in the same class.

Comment: this looks like magic. But Java does not use magic. So either the code is not the one the crashing app is built from, or the stacktrace is not from this code (which in fact is the same)

Comment: @laalto your suggestion may be right, but I've checked "near" code and unfortunatelly didn't found any `setVisibility` calls... proguard must mix my code "very deeply" :/ any idea how to inspect that? maybe mapping files generated by proguard may help in searching?

Comment: Another possibility is that the mapping file does not really belong to this build, so the deobfuscated method names are incorrect.

Comment: in fact I've checked and (sadly) I don't have stored these files (for build, which is reporting bug). I'm planning to release update in next few days, then I will keep appropriate files for further inspection. PS. log is from Crashlytics, I don't see option for uploading mapping files, but this is possible in GP console (and Firebase?). Thanks for suggestion, I think its a good clue